# JavaScript While Loop Wheres The Count Variable

Tags: javascript

After comparing the `while` and `for` loops, I have a question as to how the `while` loop keeps track of which count in the sequence it's on. A basic `for` loop goes like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

So the first time it runs, `i` equals `0` which fulfills the condition that `i` is less than `5`, so it executes the block of code. It then increments the variable `i` so in the next sequence `i` equals `1` which satisfies the condition and so on.

The `while` loop doesn't appear to have a variable that stores that sort of information. Here is a piece of code I found online.

```
function factorial(n) {
    var result = n;
    while (n > 1) {
        result = result * (n-1);
        n--;
    }
    console.log(result);
}

factorial(3);
```

So, after calling `factorial(3)`, result equals `3` which is greater than `1` so the code executes and result becomes `6`. In the next sequence, `n` equals `2` so `6` multiplied by `2` minus `1` is `6` so the final output is `6`. My question is why isn't there an `n` variable like the `i` variable in the `for` loop? When the loop decrements `n`, why isn't is doing `3` minus `1` over and over again?

Comment: What? `n` has its initial value because it's passed as a parameter to the function. It's decremented until it's equal to 1. (So the loop executes exactly `n - 1` times.) What's the problem?

Comment: Exactly. You said yourself (Brian) that `n` gets decremented to `2`. This is `> 1` so the while loop executes again. When we hit `n--` the second time, `n` is decremented from `2` to `1` (just like how in the `for` loop `i` was incremented from `1` to `2`, `2` to `3`, ...)

Comment: This is such a fundamentally basic question that you can't possibly have researched it. The condition for the loop to continue is right there, in plan English: `While n is greater than 1`. You should read a tutorial or a book on JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself: "When the loop decrements n".

If `n == 3` and you decrement it, then `n` will equal 2 and so on until it will equal 1, and the condition `while (n > 1)` will evaluate to `false` and the loop will stop.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Brian, there is a variable n, the function gets it as a parameter.

n-- decrements n by one, this is why it doesn't repeat 3 - 1 over and over again.

Comment: For sure. I think I might just be reading too much into it. Thanks.